# Issues getting return confirm to fire before button click event

Tags: c#, javascript, telerik

I am using a radbutton. On the onclick event I have a piece of code that runs an SQL query to delete a record.

I want to return a confirm message box for this but I am not having any luck getting it to run.

- I have tried adding it to the onclientclick event,
- I have tried adding it to the attributes in the code behind when the button click event fires,
- and I have tried the `Page.RegisterStartupScript("clientScript", message)`.

Each one of these is deleting the account before the return confirm is executed.

I have commented out my delete code and the message will fire then. In the adding it to the attributes case, it worked after I pushed the delete button twice.  I have been researching this for several days and have not found a suitable code yet.  Any help would be appreciated.

Updated - added code.

Code I have tried:

```
    string message = "<script language=JavaScript> alert( ' The ' );</script>";

    if (!Page.IsStartupScriptRegistered("clientScript"))
    {
        Page.RegisterStartupScript("clientScript", message);
    }
```

And

```
    RadButton btn = (RadButton)sender;

    string strMessage = "Are you sure?";

    btn.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return confirm('" + strMessage + "');");
```

Here is the button

```
    <telerik:RadButton ID="btnDeleteAccount" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Arial"
    Font-Size="11px" Skin="WebBlue" Text="Delete Account" OnClick="btnDeleteAccount_Click"
    Width="150px">
    </telerik:RadButton>
```

Comment: Please post some of the code you have tried. We can't help if we don't see code.

Comment: Can you please show the code????

Comment: you are trying for windows or web ????

Comment: Sorry, added code now.  This is for a webpage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found a piece of code that worked.  I must have been entering some incorrect javascript.

Here is the code I found that worked for me.

```
OnClientClicking="function (sender, args){args.set_cancel(!window.confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this account?'));}"
```